# Chrome Apps and Jumping Through Hoops

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I've written a simple frontend-only webapp that works fine in the browser, and I'd like to make it available on the Chrome Webstore.  It's turning out to be a huge pain though, and I'm worried that there's something I'm not getting.

I start by adding a manifest.json file to project.  It's slightly different than Firefox's manifest.webapp file, but whatever, there are no direct conflicts so I just add a few extra parameters and copy the rest over.

It looks like I need a background script to launch my app too, otherwise it will just be treated as an extension and not an app that opens in its own window.  Complicated, but I guess it gives me more control over how my app launches, so it makes sense.  So I add something like this to the manifest:

```
{
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["main.js"]
  }
}
```

And then in main.js I have something like this:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
  var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
  var width = 500; 
  var height = 300;

  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    id: "myapp",
    outerBounds: {
      width: width,
      height: height, 
      left: Math.round((screenWidth-width)/2),
      top: Math.round((screenHeight-height)/2)
    }   
  });   
});
```

Now my app is launching ok, but I'm getting an error in the console: `window.localStorage is not available in packaged apps. Use chrome.storage.local instead.`.  That's strange that I can't just use the W3 spec localStorage standard.  Looking up chrom.storage.local, it doesn't even use the standard localStorage syntax.  `getItem` is instead `get`, causing problems with using a light wrapper around localStorage without modifying my existing code.

So my question: Is this honestly what Google expects devs to go through if they want to get an app on the Chrome Webstore, or am I horribly misunderstanding something?

Comment: Some APIs are disabled, as you have noticed: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated. Have you already tried to use the [`<webview>` tag](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) instead?

Comment: Thanks for the comment (and the answers below).  I think a hosted app is going to be the best path forward for me based on my situation.  Understanding the ecosystem was my biggest problem here, maybe I'll write a blog post explaining things when I'm done to help anyone else as confused as me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider what a "Chrome App" is.

What you have tried to build is what was previously called a "packaged app", [a self-contained, nearly native application](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps). As such, it is expected that developers follow a slightly different set of rules. As RobW mentioned, you can *embed* your web app into that UI with a `<webview>` tag, but that's probably not what you're aiming to do.

If you want a web app appear in the store, and this app is already hosted somewhere and you do NOT want a UI separate from the normal browser, you're looking at the wrong app type.

A `.webapp`-defined app corresponds to [Hosted Apps](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide) in Chrome terminology. It's just a metadata file connected to your existing web app, that you can list in the Store.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Apps are an application platform, like Windows, OS X, Android, Linux, etc. As such, they have a unique set of requirements and constraints.

> Is this honestly what Google expects devs to go through if they want
>   to get an app on the Chrome Webstore, or am I horribly
>   misunderstanding something?

It seems that what you're asking is how to get something easily listed on the Chrome Web Store. From that perspective, your frustration is understandable: to get super-cheap distribution, you expect the developer effort to be super-low. But that's the "horrible misunderstanding," to use your terminology. Cheap distribution might be your goal, but it isn't Google's. The Chrome Apps platform is a distinct application platform specifically designed to ensure that apps perform well on Chromebooks and other Chrome OS devices. Incidentally, yes, part of the ecosystem is a store that helps with distribution. But that's just a small part of developing for the platform.

Take a look at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps and try out some of the sample apps. You will find that the good parts of web development are still there, but the bad parts (synchronous APIs like localStorage, a page-oriented lifetime model, dangerous inline script) are removed, while entirely new parts (new hardware and UI APIs, excellent offline behavior, better distribution, and a significantly stronger security model) are added.

The Chrome Apps platform is lean, and it fits the similarly lean Chrome OS. Spend a day or two immersing yourself in it. It's worth it. Write a quality, polished app that works well on Chromebooks, and the distribution you seek will naturally follow.